# Implementing a 16 bit register in Nand2Tetris (HDL code)

Tags: hdl, nand2tetris

think I am most of the way there, and my hardware simulator accepts the chip, but when running the test script the comparison fails half way through, I'm guessing there is an issue with feeding the output of the DFF back into the Mux. Any advice would be much appreciated!

16-bit register:
If load[t] == 1 then out[t+1] = in[t]
else out does not change

```
CHIP Register {
IN in[16], load;
OUT out[16];

PARTS:
Mux (a=dffout, b=in[15], sel=load, out= dff);
DFF (in = dff, out = dffout, out = out[15]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the entire Register script and knowing more details about the error, it is impossible to determine where the error lies.

The snippet you have posted appears to implement a single bit of the register, so it appears that you are replicating this 16 times with individual Mux and DFF components. This is a bad practice because it makes it much easier to wire up things incorrect (you probably have a typo somewhere that is causing the error) and because it makes the code hard to read.

As with higher-level programming, the recommended practice is to write your code as concisely as possible and use existing hdl components whenever possible. At this point in the course, you should already have created a Bit() component; you will find it much easier to build your Register() out of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming in very late but for any one who sees this, the supplied HDL code only takes the MSB (most significant bit at index 15) and puts it through the register. I am assuming your intention was to make a 16 bit register and load all the bits in at once right?
If so, make a 1-bit memory chip and then use 16 of those for your 16-bit register

The reason it has to be this way is because nand2tetris does not have a 16 bit DFF built-in (unless you want to make yours.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx2YM.png)